# Change parent element background position on child hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation menu which would change parent `div` background when hover on child `li` item. Actually, I just want to move the parent background.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="headerNav">
    <li class="navHome"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navServices"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li class="navFaq"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="navGallery"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="navContact"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

So, I have the `#headerNav` showing default background. When you hover over Services, I want move `#headerNav` background image 75px up. When you hover over FAQ, I want to move `#headerNav` background image 150px up, etc.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show us running example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Depending on level of browser support, you could just use CSS transition / animation to move background images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that `li` elements are list items, so its parent should be e.g. `ul` tag but not `div`. If we imagine valid HTML markup, you can use something like follows to operate `background-position` of the parent element. I used `index()` method for not hardcoding the logic.

```
$("#headerNav > li").hover(function() {
    var pos = "0 -" + ($(this).index() * 75) + "px";
    $(this).parent().css("background-position", pos);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background-position", "0 0");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rFhtP/

Comment: Though this doesn't really address the question in the title, I think this is the best solution for the OP's specific situation.

Comment: @adeneo Cat always makes the answer better :)

Comment: @VisioN Perfect answer and exactly what I'm looking for, but for some reason I can't get it working... Any ideas why? Here's my entire code:
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My site</title>
<style>
#headerNav {
    background-image: url(images/assets/menu-home.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#headerNav > li").hover(function() {

Comment: var pos = "0 -" + ($(this).index() * 75) + "px";
    $(this).parent().css("background-position", pos);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background-position", "0 0");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="headerNav">
    <li class="navHome"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navServices"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li class="navFaq"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="navGallery"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="navContact"><a href="contact-us.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user1078494 Seems that you do not include JQuery library. Use `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` instead of `code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`. And also you forgot to put your JavaScript code in the DOM ready block: `$(function() { ... });`.

Comment: OMG... (facepalm smiley needed) - I actually did have http for jQuery, but I was missing the DOM ready block... LOL, I just c/p-ed your code without thinking. Thank you very much, this is really a perfect solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using by putting a custom attribute on the li's that determine the number of pixels to move and use the jquery when hover on an item, get the attribute value then access it's parent to set it's background position using this attribute, this way it will be scalable menu and robust

```
$("#headerNav li").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background-position", $(this).attr("CustomAttributeName"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do this easily with the `hover()` function:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
    $(this.parentNode).addClass(this.className);
}, function() {
    $(this.parentNode).removeClass(this.className);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zy68z/

Comment: Adding or removing the entire classname of the `li` to/from the classname of the parent is probably a bad idea; however, you get the idea.  Another property of the `li` can be used instead, i.e. its index or a "data-" attribute.